# RMI ResultSet object passing

Tags: java

I have been trying real hard to connect JDBC with RMI. In that i need to retrieve the database result into the client console screen.I thought of passing the ResultSet object from Remote method  to the client. I dont know how to do it. Help!

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Infoimp extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Infoint,java.io.Serializable
{
    public Infoimp() throws RemoteException{
    }
    public ResultSet result() throws RemoteException
    {
        try{
                final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
                final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/STUDENTS";
                final String USER = "root";
                final String PASS = "";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                String sql = "INSERT INTO INFO VALUES (1011,'GEET','IT',8735007)";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                boolean x=stmt.execute(sql);

                sql="SELECT * FROM INFO";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                return(rs);
        }catch(Exception se){
            se.printStackTrace();

            ResultSet rs=null;
            return(rs);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to serialize the rows yourself. Your `ResultSet` isn't Remotable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't   pass `Resultset`, which is not `Serializable`. Get values from Resultset into plain java object, which is `Serializable` and pass that object.

Have a look at oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-objmodel7.html).

If you need sample code to achieve this, have a look at SE question:

[How to pass object in arguments in RMI method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736347/how-to-pass-object-in-arguments-in-rmi-method)